# jqxGrid filter row error inside jQuery-Smart-Wizard

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I am using a jqxGrid inside a jQuery-Smart-Wizard.

With the next settings on the jqxGrid it is working:

```
filterable: false,
showfilterrow: false
```

When I try to add the filter row to the jqxGrid I get the following error message, and the filter is not working:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

If I put the jqxGrid outside of the jQuery-Smart-Wizard steps then it is working with the filter also.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether all data fields in the Grid's source object has "type" set as this is mandatory.

Comment: The source object is simply an array of objects but when I copy the same grid outside of the jQuery-Smart-Wizard steps it is working without any error message.

Comment: The jqxGrid as far as I know does not accept Array of objects as source. It supports data binding to jqxDataAdapter only.

Comment: You can check it in this document: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/angularjs/angularjs.htm But as I said, it is working outside of the jQuery-Smart-Wizard, so the data displayed and the filter working as well

Comment: You can check it here: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-datasources.htm. This page shows that the source should be dataAdapter. So I guess the other approach tries to do something like that, but in general the widget expects dataAdapter always.